# How to implement a react controlled input using useReducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, react-hooks, use-reducer

My goal is to implement a React controlled input using the `useReducer` hook.

Inside the reducer I need the `event.target.value` and `event.target.selectionStart` to get the current value and caret position. So I've thought about sending the `event` as the `payload` for the `ON_CHANGE` action.

This is what I'm trying:

https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-edison-xypvn

```
function reducer(state = "", action) {
  console.log("From reducer... action.type: " + action.type);
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ON_CHANGE": {
      const event = action.payload;
      const caretPosition = event.target.selectionStart;
      const newValue = event.target.value;
      console.log("From reducer... event.target.value: " + event.target.value);
      console.log(
        "From reducer... event.target.selectionStart: " + caretPosition
      );
      return newValue;
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}

export default function App() {
  console.log("Rendering App...");

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, "");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        value={state}
        onChange={event => dispatch({ type: "ON_CHANGE", payload: event })}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

It works for the 1st letter typed, but it breaks on the 2nd.

This is the error:

> Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `target` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist(). See `react-event-pooling` for more information.

What should I do? Where do I need to call `event.persist()`. Should I do it on the `reducer` or I need to do it before sending it as a parameter, inside the `onChange()` handler.

Or is it better to send only those properties, instead of sending the full `event` object?

Like:

```
onChange={ event => 
  dispatch({ 
    type: "ON_CHANGE", 
    payload: {
      value: event.target.value,
      caretPosition: event.target.selectionStart
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just pass the `event.target.value` instead, because like the error says, [synthetic events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#overview) don't persist.

```
function reducer(state = "", action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ON_CHANGE": {
      const newValue = action.payload;
      return newValue;
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}

export default function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, "");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        value={state}
        onChange={event =>
          dispatch({ type: "ON_CHANGE", payload: event.target.value })
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit naughty-wind-egone]

Comment: I also need the `event.target.selectionStart` property. Should I send those 2 properties in the payload? Or should I call `event.persist()` and send the whole `event`. Which approach would you choose? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, pass in payload